# Draw polyline between given points on the map

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am implementing an iOS application, and I want to draw a polyline between several given coordinates on the map.

I wrote the code and got the polylines being drawn from my point reaching an infinite point. In other words the beginning point of the line starts from the my given lat and long point, but the end of the line is infinite and not the other point.

This is my code...

I filled the coordinates in a `NSMutableArray` called `routeLatitudes`.  The array cells are being filled one for latitude and one for longitude.

```
MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [routeLatitudes count]); 

for(int idx = 0; idx < [routeLatitudes count]; idx=idx+2)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;       
    workingCoordinate.latitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
    workingCoordinate.longitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:idx+1] doubleValue];  
    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate);
    pointArr[idx] = point;      
}   

// create the polyline based on the array of points. 
routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:[routeLatitudes count]];
[mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
free(pointArr);
```

and overlay delegate

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
   MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

  if(overlay == routeLine)
  {
    self.routeLineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine]        autorelease];
    self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51 green:51 blue:255  alpha:1];
    self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;

    overlayView = routeLineView;
  }
return overlayView;
}
```

So I need the lines to be drawn between the points over the map.  The beginning of the line is the first dropped pin, and the end is on the last dropped pin.

Comment: What is the routeLineView? What kind of UI element is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the code, the `routeLatitudes` array has objects listed like this:

> index 0: latitude for point 1
>   index 1: longitude for point 1
>   index 2: latitude for point 2
>   index 3: longitude for point 2
>   index 4: latitude for point 3
>   index 5: longitude for point 3
>   ...

So if `routeLatitudes.count` is 6, it actually has only 3 points.

This means the `malloc` is allocating the wrong number of points and the `polylineWithPoints` call is also specifying the wrong number of points for the overlay.

The other problem is that since `pointArr` will contain only half the objects that `routeLatitudes` has, you can't use the same index value for both arrays.

The `for` loop index counter `idx` is being incremented by 2 at each iteration because that's how the `routeLatitudes` points are layed out but then the same `idx` value is used to set `pointArr`.

So for `idx=0`, `pointArr[0]` is set but then for `idx=2`, `pointArr[2]` is set (instead of `pointArr[1]`), and so on.  This means every other position in `pointArr` is left uninitialized resulting in the lines "going to infinity".

So the corrected code might look like this:

```
int pointCount = [routeLatitudes count] / 2;
MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(MKMapPoint) * pointCount);

int pointArrIndex = 0;  //it's simpler to keep a separate index for pointArr
for (int idx = 0; idx < [routeLatitudes count]; idx=idx+2)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;       
    workingCoordinate.latitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
    workingCoordinate.longitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:idx+1] doubleValue];  
    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate);
    pointArr[pointArrIndex] = point;
    pointArrIndex++;
}   

// create the polyline based on the array of points. 
routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:pointCount];
[mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
free(pointArr);
```

Also note in the `malloc` line, I corrected `sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)` to  `sizeof(MKMapPoint)`.  This technically wasn't causing a problem because those two structs happen to be the same length but it's correct to use `sizeof(MKMapPoint)` since that's what the array is going to contain.

Comment: hey! i would like to ask, how to hide the polylines on the map? like within a button Show/Hide Polylines?
thanks :)

Comment: Get a reference to the overlay _view_ (ie. the MKPolylineView) and set its hidden property to YES/NO.  Of course, you could also just remove/add the overlay (ie. the MKPolyline).   If more details are needed or it doesn't work, please ask a new question with the code you tried.

Comment: dude, i also need to remove the polylines from over the map, not only show/hide. 
I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Please start a new question with some details on exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried (and why it didn't work, exact error messages, etc).

Comment: @AnnaKarenina hi. i have draw a line between 2 points it is shows multiple lines. please help me am in critical situation.Can i show my code?