# Google Map Kit, draw polylines for walk like google map ios

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I wants to draw polyline for walk like google map app in ios using google maps ios sdk. For more clear understanding i am uploading image that is from google map app(ios.)[image]

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11986156/3755954

Comment: There are only two points (dropped pin and current location) and the circles are polyline style which is shown in walking in the app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to achieve the dotted polyline effect? If so, I don't believe that is supported in the SDK.

You can manually create a similar effect with GMSCircles.

```
    for(int x = 0; x < [self.path count]; x++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [self.path coordinateAtIndex:x];

        //draw circle coord
        GMSCircle *circle = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:coord radius:20];
        circle.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        circle.strokeWidth = 2;

        circle.map = mapView;
    }
```

For this to really look like the original example you will probably need to add additional points onto the line in order for the circles to be evenly spaced out. For that you could do something like this.

```
    for(all the points in the path)
    {
        if(the distance from pointA to pointB is > some distance)
        {
            centerPtr = center point of pointA and pointB
            insert centerPt in path
        }
    }
```

You can turn this into a simple recursive function that should give you something similar to what you are looking for.